# How many tenses are there in English and what are they?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many tenses are there in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english)

The number of grammatical tenses in English makes it confusing as to what they are exactly and what types of tenses there are.

This seems to be complicated by Aspects and Conditionals. If we were to put them into a mix, how many total possibilities would there be, and what would they be?