# How many tenses are there in English?

Tags: verbs, tenses, modal-verbs, mood, aspect

Do we have 16 tenses in English?

With

1. future
2. present
3. past
4. future in the past

in these forms

1. simple
2. continuous
3. perfect
4. perfect continuous

Can we manipulate these together to create English tenses? For example, "**present perfect**" or "**future perfect continuous**"?

Comment: The answer to this depends on how you define "tense". I will put together a more complete response as an answer.

Comment: It also depends on how you define "English". The African American Vernacular English (AAVE) dialect has four different degrees of past tenses, and three of future tenses. Also an alternate present tense which indicates sort of a habitual activity (Which personally I find so damn handy that its really tough not to slip it into in non-AAVE conversation). You can get a far better sense of the timing of events in AAVE than you can in most other English dialects.

Comment: Related, and relevant: [Whose tense is it, anyway?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/86812/)  “As mentioned above, the current popular approach is to limit the use of the word tense to only those situations in which verb morphology is inflected to convey time information.

This view unfortunately can't work. In fact, if you applied this sort of thinking to English, not only would we not have future tenses, but we'd have neither past nor present tenses either.”

Comment: what is the tense 'future in the past'? Can you give an example?

Comment: I suspect that "future in the past" is a subjunctive: it's a different future than what actually happened. "I coulda been a contender." -> "At some time in the past, it looked like I had a future as a successful male."

Comment: The ESL definition of "future in the past" is "I would go" or "I was going to go". I think the terminology comes from the fact that "I would go" is formally the past tense of "I will go", although it's not always used that way.

Comment: @Kaz No, it is not a subjunctive.  It is remarkable what people think subjunctives are.  Compare present and future  in "He is telling me that he will go home early" with past and future-in-the-past" in "He was telling me that he would go home early." Nothing is even vaguely subjunctive there. Here, however, there is: "I insisted that she go home immediately." See the difference?

Comment: @PeterShor If today you intend to do as you will, then perhaps yesterday you already did as you would.  But yes, it is mostly oratorical/archaic/poetic/obsolete to use will/would non-modally. But it is enough to say that I am sure I will go tomorrow but yesterday I was sure I would go today. That is already a present/past inflectional distinction for will/would.

Comment: Also, the [time-travel tenses](http://technobabble.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Travel_Tenses)!

Comment: I'm guessing two questions have been combined here or something, as an old answer of mine from 18 months ago has suddenly appeared in addition to the one I left earlier today. (Though I see I pretty much agree with my previous self-- that's reassuring to know.)

Comment: Related: [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/) [Attempt at formulating verb tenses when time travel is involved?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9638/) [Differences between ways to express future actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57053/)

Comment: For linguistically minded people http://www.features.surrey.ac.uk/features/tense.html

Comment: @T.E.D. Would you please elaborate on the "alternate present tense which indicates sort of a habitual activitity"? It seems useful but I don't know that I've heard it used.

Comment: @CPRitter It's mostly done by using "be" instead of "is" (eg: "He be working," to mean something like "He is constantly working"). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Tense_and_aspect

Comment: In fiction: Dinosaur Comics' T-Rex claims to have invented the "future perfect continuous passive." http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=2300 (I suppose an example would be "I will have been being here two hours by then.") Also, in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, Adams suggests that the Future Semiconditionally Modified Subinverted Plagal Past Subjunctive Intentional is needed by time travelers.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

### What is a tense?

In linguistic terminology, "tense" is a part of verbal paradigm that refers specifically to the time of an utterance. It is impossible for any language to have more than three tenses in this sense, since any action is either past, present, or future.

In English, we do the basic tenses this way:

- Present: I **walk** to the store.
- Past: I **walked** to the store.
- Future: I **will walk** to the store.

But what is that with the word *will* there in the future tense example? It turns out that while English can refer to present and past time using inflections on the verb itself, the future tense always requires another word. Furthermore, there are multiple ways of doing this:

- I will walk to the store.
- I'm going to walk to the store.
- I'm walking to the store in five minutes.
- I'm about to walk to the store.

So while English has plenty of ways to refer to future actions, in terms of base verbal morphology there are only ***two*** tenses in English: *present* and *past*.

### So what about perfect, progressive, and the rest of that stuff?

Linguists refer to these as *aspect*. A verb's aspect refers to its duration, frequency, or completeness. English has *three* core aspects:

- Simple: I *walk* to the store.
- Progressive: I *am walking* to the store.
- Perfect: I *have walked* to the store.

Plus, we can combine progressive and perfect together as follows:

- Perfect progressive: I *have been walking* to the store.

Unfortunately, the way that these forms interact with meaning is very complex. In particular, we often use the simple present ("I walk to the store") to refer to *habitual* actions, and the simple progressive ("I am walking to the store") to refer to  *currently ongoing* actions.

### Now you've made me upset

That's because of *mood*, the other major component of the English verbal complex. Mood refers to the speaker's attitude towards the action, whether the speaker thinks the action is necessary, obligatory, inevitable, hypothetical, etc. We have a lot of moods in English, indicated by our *modal verbs*:

- I *shall walk* to the store.
- I *will walk* to the store.
- I *should walk* to the store.
- I *would walk* to the store.
- I *may walk* to the store.
- I *might walk* to the store.
- I *must walk* to the store.
- I *can walk* to the store.
- I *could walk* to the store.

Here, again, the form interacts with the meaning in a complicated way. The modal verbs *will* and *shall* tend to indicate future time more than anything really "moody", and there are constraints on which moods can be used in which tenses. Just to keep you on your toes.

Really we have 4 modal verbs which occur in present/past tense pairs: *will/would, shall/should, can/could, may/might*, and then *must* which can only be present-tense.

### And don't forget about voice

Because we also have *active voice* and *passive voice* in English, which refer to the subject and the object are assigned to the verb.

- Active: I hit a dog with my car.
- Passive: A dog was hit by a car.

These have nothing to do with tense, but they are still part of the verbal paradigm.

### Putting it all together

If you multiply all of those together you get **eighty-eight** possible combinations.

```
((5 moods × 2 tenses) + (1 defective mood)) × (4 aspects × 2 voices)
```

Don't try to memorize them all. Just try to remember the way the pieces interact, and you should be able to construct and interpret any combination that you come across. And remember that many verbs, like the past debitive perfect passive about to appear in this sentence, should rarely have ever been used by anyone.

### But it's not that simple

It never is. The preceding elements are the *core* verbal paradigm, but there are a lot of other things that English does with its verbs to indicate elements of mood, aspect, or tense. Just to name two, we have:

- Past habitual: I used to walk to the store.
- Immediate future: I'm about to walk to the store.

There are lots of other combinations of helping verbs, adverbs, and prepositions which are sometimes used to express tense-like or aspect-like things in English. Merely knowing how the core verbal paradigm fits together doesn't necessarily help you interpret these kinds of utterances. Rather, these idiomatic verbal constructions have to be learned one at a time.

Also, please do read the comments on this answer, as the commenters have brought up numerous other subtleties and distinctions which I didn't get into the main post. The final takeaway of all this discussion is that **English verbs are complex** and **you probably can't count how many forms they have**.

Have fun!

Comment: @tchrist Great link! I encourage everyone to click through to it.

Comment: This is not the [first time it's come up](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html), of course. More interesting is why anyone would want to know **any** answer to that question, since none of them are useful without many qualifications in an almost tense-free language like English.

Comment: I don't think "tense" is necessarily restricted to "past"/"present"/"future". In principle, I think you could have other dichotomies that you may end up as analysing as tense e.g. "remote past"/"near past"/"non-past", or "past-and-present" vs "past-but-not-present". (Of course, these may also reflect dichotomies *other* than tense, depending on exactly what contrasts/combines with what in the language in question.)

Comment: I don't agree with "what is tense". Semantically, there are many nuances in time. These are all tenses. The idea that something hasn't yet happened, but happens in a past relative to some future time, is a distinct tense. A hypothetical future related to some past is also a distinct tense.  English has special dedicated syntactic structures to handle tenses like these.

Comment: Semantically there are nuances in time. But the idea is that "tense" is not used to refer arbitrarily to *any* old thing that is to do with a time-related nuance.

Comment: +1 great answer Magus. I almost changed my avatar to a Frog image before doing this comment `:-)`

Comment: +1, just for this gem: _"And remember that many verbs, like the past debitive perfect passive about to appear in this sentence..."_ Nice breakdown!

Comment: What about *Ought you walk to the store?*  Or was that your defecative mood? :)  Plus I think you’ve gone and left out some of the more adventurous modes, like *Dare he walk to the store?* and *Need he walk to the store?* — there are probably others, as well.

Comment: An early grammar of English - I think it's Alexander Gil's _Logonomia Anglica_ of 1614 or thereabouts - carefully displays the paradigm of the "future subjunctive": _that I may be hereafter_; _that thou mayest be hereafter_; _that he may be hereafter_ etc.

Comment: I disagree with this: `It is impossible for any language to have more than three tenses in this sense, since any action is either past, present, or future.` Some languages have tenses that distinguish between how long ago in the past something was, and so have a finer-grained distinction than just past/present/future.

Comment: Is the *will/would* et al. not a matter of indicative/subjunctive rather than present/past?

Comment: @tchrist What about the following? "Tomorrow I *would* go, if I still wanted to"

Comment: It’s true but misleading to say “…we often use the simple present to refer to habitual actions”. In contemporary English, the progressive form (“be doing”) almost always denotes simple present or future tense, and the simple present form (“do”) refers to habitual action. The exceptions are statives, which are ubiquitous—and there’s yet another distinction.

Comment: @tchrist And let us not forget the passive-aggressive voice: *Your stupid dog was hit by* my *car.*

Comment: Serious question about modal verbs. You say "*must* which can only be present-tense." What does that say about constructions like *must have*? As in "I must have dropped my keys walking to the store." Is that fulfilling a different part of language than a modal verb? Is it because you're really expressing uncertainty that the paradox defies normal language patterns? I'm trying to think of a good construction for *must have been*...

Comment: @PatrickM, *must have (been)* is present tense, perfective aspect.

Comment: The perfect construction is *not* an aspect: it has nothing to do with the internal temporal structure of events. Nor is it tense. It is a construction which alters the temporal reference point from the time of utterance to some time in the past, which the past/non-past tense distinction then uses as its reference frame.

Comment: How are modal verbs used in the past tense?  It seems like "I may walk to the store" and "I might walk to the store" are both in the present tense.

Comment: @patrickm Would "I must have been swimming when i lost the keys." be a good construction for must have been?

Comment: The *futurate* does not require 'another word' to talk about the future.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ, re: "Really we have 4 modal verbs which occur in present/past tense pairs: _will/would_, _shall/should_, _can/could_, _may/might_, and then _must_ which can only be present-tense." and your comment to Patrick -- so you would say "I would have done that by tomorrow", "I can do that", "I could do that" are in the past, present, and past tense respectively?

Answer (score 24):

Almost all grammarians recognize only two tenses in English, present and past. That is because only they require a change in the finite form of the verb. Constructions such as the present progressive or past perfect are analysed in terms of aspect, although the present and past tenses express aspect too.

For example, regular verbs have four forms. In the case of *walk* they are *walk, walks, walking, walked*. In the third person singular, the present tense is *walks* and the past tense is *walked*. A clause such as *he is walking* is made up of the present tense of *be* and the present participle of *walk* and expresses progressive aspect.

**EDIT:**

This is a view held by at least three reputable professional linguists. R L Trask, formerly Professor of Linguistics at the University of Sussex) in ‘Language and Linguistics: The Key Concepts’:

> English has only two tenses.

David Crystal in ‘The Cambridge Encylopedia of the English Language’:

> There is . . a two-way tense contrast in English: *I walk* vs *I walked* -
>   present tense vs past tense.

Bas Aarts, Professor of English Linguistics at University  College London in ‘Oxford Modern English Grammar’:

> English has only two grammatically encoded tenses, the *present* tense
>   and the *past* tense.

Whoever downvoted my answer is downvoting these three as well.

Functional grammar gets round these difficulties to some extent with its concepts of Finite and Predicator. In a clause such as:

> He was lying on his back

the Finite is *was* and the Predicator *lying*.
In a clause such as:

> It occurred to me . . .

the Finite is [past] and the Predicator *occurred*.

But these are deep waters.

Comment: I did not understand would you please give me a little more description on it?

Comment: @Mohammad Rafiee I have expanded my answer a little, but aspect is a fairly complex topic, and not really suited to discussion here. All finite verb forms have a present or past tense with or without other elements to express the way in which the speaker views the timing of the action, state or condition described.

Comment: @ tchrist. It isn’t a tense at all, but the plain form of the verb. However, I suspect we have tried the OP's patience long enough.

Comment: @tchrist: It's not the same, because _they walk_ can be made past by the addition of _-ed_. In the subjunctive construction _that he walk_, it can't. The _walk_ in _they walk_ may have the same shape as the plain form, but its syntactic role implies an inflected form. The inflection was present in Old English, but is now lost. (And, as I may have said elsewhere, there seem to be good grounds for not regarding _she were_ as subjunctive at all.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6417/discussion-between-barrie-england-and-tchrist)

Comment: I'm surprised to see so many people call it the *present* tense rather than the *non-past* tense.

Answer (score 18):

Once upon a time I found a nice [map of English tenses](http://www.jamesabela.co.uk/intermediate/Grammar/Tenses.jpg).
[image]

See also [this variation](http://www.mindmeister.com/88456543/english-grammar-tenses).

Comment: Link "this variation" as an image we can download? Rather than some web service which goads visitors into joining their databases?

Answer (score 16):

The appropriate answer to this question depends a little on your purpose, and in any case there's no single, consensually agreed upon answer.

If you don't mean "tense" to have a very strict theoretical interpretation, and just want "a list of the combinations of auxiliaries/verb forms", then pretty much all logical combinations that you can make from [will/would] - [have] - [simple tense / be + ...ing] are possible, allowing for the regular grammar of how these elements are combined (so you can have a modal with the infinitive 'have', or else a conjugated form of 'have'), and also for the slight cyclicity in that you can form a passive with 'be' + past participle, where 'be' itself can have (pretty much) any of the compound forms permitted by this formula.

That said, and perhaps most interestingly, not all speakers appear to allow exactly the same set of combinations. So for example, some, but not all speakers, appear to allow sentences such as:

> The road has not been being built for several days.

Therefore, I wouldn't get too bogged down in trying to memorise a "definitive list"-- there's not really such a thing.

From a more theoretical perspective, it's common to take the view that English has only two tenses: present and past. Other periphrastic constructions that are loosely "time-related" would be analysed as containing markers of other phenomena such as aspect or modality. However, there isn't a consensus on this analysis.

Comment: Absolutely agree there's no clear-cut answer to how many "acceptable" tense-related forms there are. If I'd've been caught off-guard, I might have **said** [had have](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/) was a valid "hypothetical past tense" marker. So the only bulletproof answer is "two" - present and past.

Comment: Your structure of "[will/would] - [have] - [simple tense / be + ...ing]" is neat but might require *simple tense* to include the naked infinitive and the past participle.

Answer (score 13):

As you might expect, the answer to this question really depends on your definition of "tense".

If you take a very strict definition of tense as being something like the "grammaticalisation of location in time", then you generally end up concluding that English has two tenses, which you might call "past" vs "non-past" (or "past" vs "present" or... well, it doesn't particularly matter, they're just labels: the point is there's two of them). Other components of verbal constructions are then grammaticalisations of *other* phenomena: aspect, voice, phase, mood etc, which themselves may even get broken down into further categories. This view has the advantage that you're "calling a spade a spade": you have a fairly clear phenomenon that you're attaching fairly consistent label to. You have a "1:1 match" between label and phenomenon, if you like.

Another, more informal, view is to consider "tenses" as being the full range of structures, affixes etc that you can "build around" a verb without altering the range of possible subjects, objects etc that can be associated with the verb (i.e. items that don't have their own *argument structure*, to use the technical term).

Informally, especially in informal foreign language classes, it's common to use the latter definition. That then leaves two problems:

- where do you draw the line between what actually consitutes encoding of "time" as opposed to other things?
- is there actually a "fixed list" of all the combinations?

In the first case, you might say that "will" marks "future tense". But on the other hand, when you actually look at how "will" is used, it isn't really encoding just "futureness" but a hots of other things. And other modals like "should", "would", "could", "must" etc also encode a host of things-- in other words, there's not necessarily anything particularly special or "uniquely tense-related" about "will" compared to other modal verbs. (This does arguably happen with "past tense" too, incidentally: at the end of a game show when the host says "Let's look at what *was* behind the curtain", the car/toaster in question is actually still there-- the "past" tense is encoding something other than simple "pastness" here.)

Then there is the problem that in English unlike, say, French, the range of possibilities of 'syntactic real estate' that you can put around the verb without changing its argument structure is quite large and not precisely delimited. (It's actually not 100% delimited even in French, but close enough for practical purposes.) Speakers will probably agree that "was built" and "was building" are fine. But, for example, if you ask a number of speakers whether in the 'range of possibilities' they would include cases such as "was been being built", you will get different answers. So it isn't really possible to give a precise number. (It's also not really clear why a precise number matters :)

Comment: I don't agree with this theory, because the rules by which certain verbs are combined to create tenses are in fact entrenched in the English grammar. Although a sentence like "By this time tomorrow I will have arrived in London" only uses the nonpast tenses of verbs (*will* and *have*) and a past participle (*arrived*), they are not used arbitrarily. The *will* verb has a special role which is part of the grammar, and *have* has a special role with past participles. The meaning of *will have arrived* must be learned as a rule: it doesn't follow in a straightforward way from the combination.

Comment: There are two verbs in "*She always insists that he call her from work"* Are those two verbs in the same "tense"?  Certainly both are in the 3rd-person singular. And yet they are inflectionally distinct, which certainly smells funny if they are supposed to be the same "tense".

Comment: Well, in my analysis, "call" would be an infinitive, if that's what's bothering you-- I'm not sure it warrants positing an extra tense (in a binary tense system, it wouldn't be marked for "past tense"-- in principle, you could have infinitives marked for tense, but I don't think this is an example of such a phenomenon).

Comment: @Kaz - even if what you say is true, I'm not sure how it really contradicts my answer.

Comment: @neil coffey: thanks for you descriptive answer actually the number doe not matter I just need an over view over english tenses.

Answer (score 12):

English has present and past tense.

Forms of the verb *be*, in either tense, can be used with an *-ing* verb. This is the progressive aspect.

> I [see / saw / am seeing / was seeing] that.

The verb *have* can be combined with any of those. This is the perfect.

> I [have seen / had seen / have been seeing / had been seeing] that.

And any of those eight combinations can be combined with a modal verb: *may/might*, *can/could*, *shall/should*, *will/would*, and *must*. (The past tense of *must* is *must*.)

> I [may see / might see / may be seeing / might be seeing / may have seen / might have seen / may have been seeing / might have been seeing] that.

This gives sixteen combinations in all.

Conditionals complicate the choice of which combination to use, but they don’t add new combinations.

In case it is not clear: only the first verb in the chain is ever marked for past tense. The verb immediately after the perfect *have* is always the past participle. The verb immediately after the progressive *be* is marked with *-ing*.

These cover the ways verbs are most often used in main clauses. From here it gets more complicated, because there are also many other things to know about how verbs are used—the imperative, subjunctive, infinitive, gerund, passive, and so on.

Answer (score 8):

There are only two tenses in English, past and present.

- jump, jumped.
- sing, sang.
- go, went.

The "number of grammatical tenses" you refer to are compound-tenses and modals, not tenses in their own right.

Comment: So, the future doesn't exist?

Comment: It's not a 'tense', it is a mode. Compare English and Pali: *I go, I went, I will go; kamami, akamami, kamissami*. Or Latin if you prefer: *ambulo, ambulabit, ambulavi* (Latin experts correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: @FractalizeR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense#English

Comment: @trideceth12: Latin has six indicative tenses and four subjunctive tenses and all can occur in both active and passive forms.

Comment: @trideceth: I id not get my answer from your response , I am not interested in wo4d composition i just need an over view over english tenses, anyway thanks for your attention

Answer (score 5):

There are 16, I believe: Past, Present, Future, and Future-in-the-Past, and each of those can be Indefinite (called Simple now), Continuous, Perfect and Perfect Continuous.

4x4 = 16 different combinations.

Comment: I think this answer best matches the question; I expanded on it in mine. +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a list of tenses at http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/tenses. This page seems to cover everything except the imperative mood. If you need practice in actual tense use, try http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/tenses.

Comment: Since the question mentions tense and aspect, I think the link you have provided is not clear enough because it doesn't separate the two.

Comment: Hi @ssakl, thanks your link! I'm from Hungary, Europe(I'm studying British English for 8-9 school years); I have some problems with using these tenses(listed in the table) - so I don't really know, when or where may I use different tenses. (Mainly the Perfect & the Perfect Progressive make me problems.) Can you or someone else *give me examples/teach me the usage* for these things for the Use section (maybe in separated question)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between tense in the loose sense it is used by language teachers, and the strict definition relating to time alone that is agreed in linguistics.  Teachers will typically give a list of around 16 as suggested in the question and some of the answers.

In addition there is the infinitive form, which is noun-like, and the active and passive participles, which are like nouns and adjectives, and don't strictly have tense (notwithstanding them also being known as present and past participles, it is actually aspect that is in focus, continuing versus completed, and the rest of the construction can locate the -ing progress or -ed completion in the past, present or future in both cases): I was working all night and will have finished by lunchtime.

There is also a difference between words being marked morphologically for tense or periphrastically for tense, that is through the use of a phrase with additional words.
Linguists would thus say there are just 2 morphologically marked tenses in English. Of course in general we can divide any dimension, even time, into more than two parts. However only the present and past are real (observed fact) and other constructions allow us to express the irreal (intentions, plans, possibilities or alternatives - beyond fact).

These differences are a bit arbitrary, and there are additional dimensions as discussed in great detail (but still incompletely) by JSB and others: aspect, voice and mood/mode. What has been neglected in particular is the indicative, imperative and interrogative moods.

In English all these possible combinations (over 100 by my count) are mediated by the infinitive (bare or preceded by "to"), two morphological tenses (marked for past by -ed as a rules, unmarked for present except for the -s marker of 3rd person singular) and the two participles (marked by -ed and -ing) in combination with auxiliary and modal verbs.

It is a bit arbitrary to say that some verbs are auxiliary verbs and some are modal verbs and there are many other constructions other than those traditional auxiliaries and modals.
The use of "be/is/are" and "have/has" as auxiliaries with participles is really/originally just the standard predicative construction (it is finishing/finished/finite) and the standard possessive construction (it has finished; it has a nice finish/style; it has style).

The modal constructions listed by JSB have the distinctive property that their roots don't act as infinitives (although future marker "will" does in its primary sense relating to acts of the will), and the main verb that follows is bare (without "to").  But there are many other constructions that affect mood/intention/likelihood/definiteness:

naked infinitive with implicit/explicit +that+: insisted, suggested, mandated, ordered...

with requisite +to+: to have to, to be supposed to, to want to, to intend to, to desire to, ...

without infinitive form but requiring +to+: ought to, ...

Answer (score -1):

The question is are continuous forms genuine tenses or mere pseudo-tenses.
As "I'm working" is basically nothing else as "I'm in the act of working" I don't see a reason to speak of 16 tenses.
Grammatically this is a simple present tense of to be + a special complement emphasizing the aspect of continuity.

Another important thing. Latin grammars have developed an excellent form of a conjugation table. But I have never seen a reasonable conjugation table in English grammars that gives learners an idea of the conjugation system. Maybe that is the cause why there are so many questions about tenses.
To mix in conjugation tables simple forms and continuous forms is a horrible custom.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks!  "habe":  That was the German finger that came between.