# Are "I will have been going" and "I would have been going" rarely used today?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, future

As far as I know these are tenses that you do not often use. Am I right?

> Will have been + verb+ing
>
> Would have been + verb+ing

Comment: I do not use them often; I try not to abuse tenses. I've been wrong before, I will have been wrong again.

Comment: Verb+ing = gerund ?"I would have been playing soccer if my work was complete"

Comment: @argot: This is a present participle; using 'gerund' here is at best highly disputable.

Comment: Thank you all so much. but, would you please kindly answer my original question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who knows which tenses of English are not used or used merely?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147601/who-knows-which-tenses-of-english-are-not-used-or-used-merely)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many tenses are there in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english)

Comment: meta: The new question (http://english.stackexchange.com/q/147702/14666) of the OP shows that the comments and answers on this page have been of not much avail to them. The new question supersedes this and so this post may be closed as redundant.

Comment: English is not my native language, but I'm good at it. Once I used this construction: will+ have been+ doing and my supervisor was so astonished, saying I must not use this and it's non grammatical

Answer (score 6):

You are right that the two constructions are not often used. This is because they express uncommon ideas. Both are grammatical, however, and could be used as follows:

> By the time I retire I *will have been working* here for 45 years.
>
> If you had called me 10 minutes ago, I *would have been sleeping*.

Comment: +1 "This is because they express uncommon ideas." It's not that these tenses are avoided, it's simply that they are not often needed.

Comment: It's just that these aren't tenses. They're just a couple of the many thousands of possible English auxiliary verb constructions, most of which are used infrequently because there [are so many of them](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist).

Comment: @JohnLawler So do linguisticians not consider the future-perfect a tense?

Comment: No more than they consider the Past Usitative Necessitive a tense. What you call "future-perfect" is a combination of the modal auxiliary _will_ with a perfect construction. One can do the same with the other modal auxiliaries _may, might, must, can, could, shall, should,_ and _would_. And one can do the same with all kinds of other constructions, like the "Past Usitative Necessitive Tense" of _go_, *I used to have to go.*

Comment: Oh, and it's _linguist_, by the way. As you are surely aware, nobody ever uses _linguistician._

Comment: I do see how this can answer the OP's question. Please also see my meta comment at the OP.